# I am unsure if this question is not being answered due to a specific date

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posted the question [How to ask for a change in administrative graduate pay politely?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54641/how-to-ask-for-a-change-in-administrative-graduate-pay-politely)

I am unsure if this question is not being answered due to a specific date. Should I remove the part that mentions my meeting occurring on a specific date, or is there something else wrong about the post? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say why other people are not answering this question, but I can say why *I* wouldn't attempt to answer this question. It's for two closely related problems:

- **Too much confusing detail**: There are a lot of details highly specific to your university's policies, which are difficult to understand and keep track of. If we actually *need* to know all of those details to answer your question, then it's probably too specific (see "Can I ask about my specific situation?" in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).) If we *don't* need to know all these specific details, then they are confusing and somewhat offputting to potential answerers. (And there are some details we *definitely* don't need to know, like the details of the specific preliminary exams.)
- **Lack of general, easy to comprehend description of your scenario**: The general question you ask is "How do I ask for a change in administrative graduate pay raise politely to my graduate department advisor with optimal chances of success?" In order to understand what you mean by "administrative graduate pay raise," I have to wade through all the details I mentioned above, because there's no [tl;dr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR) description of what you mean.

It might be better if you replaced all the detail with something like this (I don't know if I'm representing your situation accurately, because I find the details somewhat confusing, but this is my best shot):

> **tl;dr** Because I followed a "non-standard" accelerated path through preliminary exams, I am not eligible for any of my department's standard summer funding options. How can I politely ask for a pay raise to help me cover the summer?
>
> Specifically, in my department, graduate students who have not completed preliminary exams are eligible for "prelim funding" in the summer. I am no longer eligible for this funding, because I passed my preliminary exams early. Students who have passed oral exams and completed a certain number of credits are eligible for extra pay in the spring semester to help cover the summer, but even if I pass my oral exams I won't have enough credits in time to qualify for this funding (again, because I am "ahead" of the standard path at my institution). My research advisor has informed me that there is no research funding available this summer, and he has no further advice for me.
>
> The graduate school has informed me that my department has the right to change pay level policy under certain conditions. I have scheduled to meet with my graduate department advisor on Monday. How do I ask for a change in administrative graduate pay raise politely to my graduate department advisor with optimal chances of success?